# Cascaded macros in gcc C++14 vs msvc++ 2015

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

I have the following code working under msvc 2015:

```
#define CLASS_JS_PSG_PROPERTY_EX(PROPERTY, VALUE) \
static bool Get##PROPERTY(/*irrelevant params here...*/) \
{ \
...
 some particular code
...
    return true; \
}

#define CLASS_JS_PSG_PROPERTY(VALUE) \
CLASS_JS_PSG_PROPERTY_EX(##VALUE, VALUE)

...

#define kProp 1

CLASS_JS_PSG_PROPERTY_EX(Version, kProp)

CLASS_JS_PSG_PROPERTY(kProp)
```

This should define methods named `GetVersion` and `GetkProp`.

Now, this gives the following error under gcc C++14 (actually TDM-GCC-64):

`pasting "(" and "kProp" does not give a valid preprocessing token`

How should be written in order to compile under **gcc C++14** and **msvc 2015**?

Comment: Try `CLASS_JS_PSG_PROPERTY_EX(VALUE, VALUE)`.

Comment: In this case it would try to generate functions with a names as `Get"Version"` or `Get"kProp"`.

Comment: That should only happen with `#VALUE`, not `VALUE`.

Comment: My bad, I wanted to say that content of Version or kProp is in there. The container macro will replace the parameters with their content and pass them to the inner macro (as strings if they are strings, as "1", if they are int having 1 as value).

Comment: See `#define kProp 1`. It is already pre-processed, so it won't use the name `kProp`, but the value, `1`.

Comment: So, my issue is that MSVC++ accepts handling `##` as a unary operator, or, when it detects a not concatenable token, like `(`, it considers the first token as empty string somehow and it passes further the token following `##`, to the inner macro in my case.

Comment: MSVC preprocessor is famously non-conforming, and you are relying on this non-conformity. In `CLASS_JS_PSG_PROPERTY_EX(##VALUE, VALUE)`, `##` is not a unary operator - it's a binary operator that glues `(` and `VALUE` into a single token `(VALUE`. This is not a valid preprocessing token, so the program is ill-formed. But MSVC preprocessor doesn't act on a stream of tokens (as it should) but a stream of characters, and so it later breaks this nonsensical token back up into pieces (which a conforming preprocessor would never do).

Comment: Actually I try to get rid of MSVC++, but I need to make the transition compiling with the first tool used until I can drop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is - if you don't want a name to get expanded as a macro, you must pass it to `##` operator right away - but the result of concatenation must be a valid token. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define CLASS_JS_PSG_PROPERTY_EX_HELPER(GetName) \
static bool GetName() { return true; }


#define CLASS_JS_PSG_PROPERTY_EX(PROPERTY, VALUE) \
CLASS_JS_PSG_PROPERTY_EX_HELPER(Get##PROPERTY)

#define CLASS_JS_PSG_PROPERTY(VALUE) \
CLASS_JS_PSG_PROPERTY_EX_HELPER(Get##VALUE)


#define kProp 1

CLASS_JS_PSG_PROPERTY_EX(Version, kProp)

CLASS_JS_PSG_PROPERTY(kProp)

int main() {
    std::cout << GetVersion() + GetkProp();
}
```

Works with [gcc](http://rextester.com/UBA3586) and [MSVC](http://rextester.com/DAXTJ40209)

The reason your original code appears to work with MSVC is because MSVC preprocessor is famously non-conforming - it operates on a stream of characters (wrong), rather than a stream of tokens (right). In `CLASS_JS_PSG_PROPERTY_EX(##VALUE, VALUE)`, `##` is not a unary operator as you suggest - it's a binary operator that glues `(` and `VALUE` into a single token `(VALUE`. This is not a valid preprocessing token, so the program is ill-formed, which is what GCC complains about. But MSVC preprocessor later breaks this nonsensical token back up into pieces (which a conforming preprocessor would never do).